# Symfony protect with HTTP Basic Authentication

Tags: symfony, security, basic-authentication

I have an existing site built with Symfony 2.8 and I would like to add an extra layer of security by enabling HTTP Basic Auth **only when a parameter is set to true** in parameters.yml. Is it possible?

The site already has a form login enabled but I would like to **hide the site completely** with basic authentication if the parameter is `true`.

This is my security.yml:

```
main:
    pattern:             .*
    context:             user
    form_login:
        provider:       fos_userbundle
        login_path:     /user/login
        use_forward:    false
        check_path:     /user/login_check
        failure_path:   null
        default_target_path: /
    logout:
        path:           /user/logout
        target:         /user/login
    anonymous:          true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I didn't want to interfere with existing authentication I ended up using Apache:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mysite.com
    ServerAlias www.mysite.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mysite/current/web
    <Directory /var/www/html/mysite/current/web>
        AllowOverride None
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from All

        FallbackResource /app.php

        # THIS IS THE INTERESTING PART
        # --->
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Restricted Content"
        AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
        Require valid-user
        # <---
    </Directory>

    # uncomment the following lines if you install assets as symlinks
    # or run into problems when compiling LESS/Sass/CoffeeScript assets
    # <Directory /var/www/project>
    #     Options FollowSymlinks
    # </Directory>

    # optionally disable the fallback resource for the asset directories
    # which will allow Apache to return a 404 error when files are
    # not found instead of passing the request to Symfony
    <Directory /var/www/html/mysite/current/web/bundles>
        FallbackResource disabled
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mysite_error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mysite_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I created HTTP users and password with this command:

```
sudo htpasswd -c /etc/apache2/.htpasswd stage
```

The `-c` arguments needs to be here only the first time you are creating the file.

For more info: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-password-authentication-with-apache-on-ubuntu-14-04